# Erro Python+HTML+SQLAlchemy

Tags: html, python, flask, sqlalchemy

Olá
Estou tentando fazer um procedimento simples, mas empaquei no problema abaixo. Tenho o objetivo simples de passar um parâmetro e filtrar uma lista de associados. Tenho os seguintes códigos:

Python

`@app.route("/listafiltrada/<int:doc>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def listafiltrada(doc):
    associados = Associado.query.filter_by(Documento=doc)
    return render_template("listafiltrada.html", associado=associados)`

Este é o código que envia o parâmtro:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('listafiltrada') }}" method="GET">
        Nome<input type="text" id="doc" name="doc">
        <input type="submit" value="FILTRAR">
        <br>
    </form>
```

E este é código que recebe:

```
<body>
    <h1>Lista Filtrada</h1>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <table border="4">
            <tr>
                <td>IdAssociado</td>
                <td>Nome</td>
                <td>Telefone</td>
                <td>Documento</td>
                <td>E-mail</td>
                <td>Excluir</td>
                <td>Atualizar</td>
            </tr>
            {% for i in associado %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ i.IdAssociado }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.Nome }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.Telefone }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.Documento  }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.Email }}</td>
                <td><a href="/excluir/{{ i.IdAssociado }}">X</a></td>
                <td><a href="/atualizar/{{ i.IdAssociado }}">Atualizar</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </form>

    <a href="/index">Voltar</a>
</body>
```

Mas ao executar o procedimento o seguinte erro aparece: werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'listafiltrada'. Did you forget to specify values ['doc']?

Como resolver isso?
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

A configuração de parâmetros como você criou na view requer que o parâmetro ("doc") seja passado na parte de caminho da URL, não como dado de um GET.

Isso é, essa configuração está esperando algo do tipo:

`http://localhost/23`, mas o GET pelo formulário está passando o parâmetro como:
`http://localhost/?doc=23`

Troque o código da sua view para algo como:

```
@app.route("/listafiltrada/", methods=['GET'])
def listafiltrada():
    doc = request.args.get("doc")
    if not doc:
         # redireciona para view de quando não houver o ID

    associados = Associado.query.filter_by(Documento=doc)
    return render_template("listafiltrada.html", associado=associados)
```

Comment: Olá jsbueno, agradeço sua resposta. Funcionou bem, somente tive que alterar o código "doc = request.get("doc")" para "doc = request.args.get('doc')", pois o sistema tinha me retornado o seguinte erro: "AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'get'". Muito obrigado!

Comment: Isso - arrumei na resposta - pensei uma coisa e digitei outra - é que o `get` é usado diretamnte em dicionários, e `.GET` é usado no objeto request de alguns outros frameworks (no lugar do "args")